# how to convert Mat datatype to Unsigned Short pointer

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have some module of image processing pipeline written in c++ where unsigned short * is being used as a buffer to store image data for further processing.

I have implemented some functionalities in OpenCV which uses Mat data type for storing images which is working fine as a standalone on images. i want to combine both functionalities.

How to type cast unsigned short * data type  to cv::Mat ?

How to type cast cv::Mat data type to unsigned float* ?

Any help will be highly appreciable.

```
    // snippet of code..

    // bayer_Bilinear function requires image datatype unsigned short

    void bayer_Bilinear( unsigned short *bayer, unsigned short *rgb, int sx , int sy);

    int main( ){

        //----------------------read bayr file---------------------------
            unsigned short imageSize;
            unsigned short * src;
            unsigned short * dst;
            // Open the file
            FILE * file = fopen("bayer.raw","r");

            imageSize=Width * Height; // 16bit/pixel

            // Create a buffer
            src = new unsigned short [imageSize];

            // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
            fread(src,2,imageSize,file);
            fclose (file);

        dst = new unsigned short [imageSize];

    // sending pixel data to bayer function....
            bayer_Bilinear(src, dst, 8, Height);

    // here i want to convert unsigned float * dst to Mat so i can write using opencv 

        imwrite("got.jpg",dst);
    //-- in the same way i have one function to do gamma correct
    // in this function i want to convert Mat back to unsigned sort for calculation 

    gamma (unsigned short * src, unsigned short *dst, int val);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put a few line of code to show exactly what you have and what you're missing. Are you storing in the `unsigned short*` 1 channel (gray) images?  2 bytes per pixel?

Comment: i am converting bayer data to rgb then doing fish eye correction.
reading Bayer data is done using unsigned short .I have written opencv code  for fish eye correction which requires Mat data type.
my problem is how to integrate them also for convenient and checking the output at each instance, i am writing to an image using opencv.

Comment: @user3805574 Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cv::Mat pointing to already allocated data:

```
 Mat::Mat(Size size, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

see [the OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat%28Size%20size,%20int%20type,%20void*%20data,%20size_t%20step%29)